# Not able to read data from Firebase realtime database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored the comments under a post in firebase realtime database. The problem i have is that when i try to parse out the data from firebase i get an error that says Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. So for example if i try to pront the data stored under degree, i get this nil error. But when i print "comments" instead of the "degree" i successfully fetch the data. My database structure looks like this.

[image: Firebase database]

```
 func obeserveComments() {
    
    // get auto-id of post
    let commentKey = self.keyFound
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(commentKey)
    var tempComments = [Comments]()

    postRef.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
                    if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                        if let comments = dict["comments"] as? [String:Any] {
                        let degree = comments["reply degree"] as! String
                     //   let name = comments["reply name"] as! String
                      //  let text = comments["reply text"] as! String
                      //  let university = comments["reply university"] as! String
                       // let photoURL = comments["reply url"] as! String
                      //  let url = URL(string: photoURL)
                     //   let timestamp = comments["timestamp"] as! Double
                        print(degree)
                        
                    }
                    }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @aytroncb is a good answer, I prefer to leave Firebase data 'Firebasy' as long as possible. In other words coverting to dictionaries looses ordering and and find code like this

```
[String: [String: [String: Any]]]
```

To be very hard to read.

I prefer

```
let snap = snapshot.childSnapshot("comments") //snap becomes a DataSnapshot
```

So my solution maintains the order and leverages .childSnapshot to leave data in it's DataSnapshot form.

```
func readPostComments() {
    let postRef = self.ref.child("posts") //self.ref points to my firebase
    postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for postSnap in allPosts {
            print("postId:  \(postSnap.key)")
            let commentsSnap = postSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments") //will be a DataSnapshot
            let allComments = commentsSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            for commentSnap in allComments {
                print("  commentId:  \(commentSnap.key)")
                let replyDegree = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "reply_degree").value as? String ?? "No Degree"
                let replyName = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "reply_name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
                print("      degree: \(replyDegree)  by: \(replyName)")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

EDIT

For a single post, remove the top part of the code that reads in and iterates over all posts.

```
func readCommentsForOnePost() {
    let postRef = self.ref.child("posts")
    let postCommentRef = postRef.child("post_0")
    postCommentRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print("postId:  \(snapshot.key)")
        let commentsSnap = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments") //will be a DataSnapshot
        let allComments = commentsSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for commentSnap in allComments {
            print("  commentId:  \(commentSnap.key)")
            let replyDegree = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "reply_degree").value as? String ?? "No Degree"
            let replyName = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "reply_name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
            print("      degree: \(replyDegree)  by: \(replyName)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay! this actually did the trick. However the only problem now is that it loads all the comments in the database as opposed to the comments under the particular post of interest. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CodingForFun333 That was to show how to do just that - go through all of them. If you want to narrow it down, just change the reference, and remove the section that loads in all posts. I updated the answer.

Comment: Amazing Jay, it works great now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Its because firebase is returning your data like this

```
{
   "MAKFW244kdL)Cw;1": [Array of data],
   "LOPSw!35pa3flAL4": [Array of data],
   "ALV34VR4_A6Vn1a": [Array of data]
}
```

So change your initial casting of snapshot.value to this:

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: Any]]
```

then loop through that new dictionary like this:

```
for objectJson in dict.values {
    
    if let comments = objectJson["comments"] as? [String: [String: Any]] {
        for commentJson in comments.values {
            let degree = commentJson["reply_degree"] as? String
        }
    }

}
```

### Update

Just read through your post again and noticed your trying to access the `comments` directly with a key, your first going to need to provide the `PostId`. Then you can use the above code to loop through the objects

```
 let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postID)
```

alternatively I believe you can have the comments returned as a normal list by doing something like this:

```
 let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("\(postID)/{id}")
```

Comment: Good answer. Just for clarity, the objects returned from Firebase are DataSnapshots, not JSON (as in `objectJson` as a var name), but they contain JSON style data. Nothing technically wrong at all with that name. It's often easier to work with the DataSnapshots at a higher level then digging into the JSON itself. Also casting data to a dict like this`let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: Any]]` looses ordering - may not be a big deal but it does trip up some people. Upvote for you!