# Firebase dataSnapshot sub-node

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to snapshot the shopping lists of a user. The snapshot works fine, except for the products node.

Link to db: [image: Firebase Database image]

This is my observer:

```
func observeLists(callBack: @escaping (_ list: [List]) -> Void){
        let dbRef = database.child("list").child(ShareData.shared.userId)
        
        dbRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "completed").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            var newItems: [List] = []
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot {
                    let groceryItem = List(snapshot: snapshot)
                    newItems.append(groceryItem)
                }
            }
            callBack(newItems)
        })
    }
```

And this is my init(snapshot) from struct List

```
init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        
        let id = snapshot.key
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let products = value?["products"] as? [Product] ?? []
        let completed = value?["completed"] as? Bool ?? false
        let storeId = value?["storeId"] as? String ?? ""
        let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""

        self.init(id, products, completed, storeId, name)
    }
```

Comment: While your coding style will work with @frankvanpuffelen answer (which should be accepted) - I recommend leaving Firebase data as DataSnapshots as long as possible, it's way easier to read and deal with. See my unrelated answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68315050/not-able-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database/68320540#68320540) on how to do that (instead of casting to a thousand different arrays of String: Value pairs). e.g. your [Products] array is actually a DataSnapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `products` node in your database is not an array of products (`[Product]`), but rather a dictionary/map (`[String: Product]`).